# G+ integration listing activities using jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-plus, jinja2

I'm trying to represent a list of G+ activities in a traditional HTML (app engine app). I made a call to G+ service. I get the collection. Then I send this variable using Jinja2. Finally when trying to iterate over the HTML I have problems.

main.py

```
   actividades = servicio.activities().list(userId='me', collection='public', maxResults='2').execute(http=http)

   plantilla_values = {
      'actividades': actividades,
   }

   template = Entorno_Jinja.get_template('index.html')
   self.response.write(template.render(plantilla_values))
```

index.html (using jinja2)

```
    {% for a in actividades%}
      <li>{{a}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

"actividades" variable value:

```
{u'updated': u'2014-10-20T16:55:25.402Z', u'kind': u'plus#activityFeed', u'nextPageToken': u'Cg0Qq5bbpOO7wQIgACgBEhQIABCQ95Om2bvBAhjo-LTftLHBAhgC', u'title': u'Google+ List of Activities for Collection PUBLIC', u'etag': u'"Vea_b94Y77GDGgRK7gFNPnolKQw/TIMAz5AmENqGsq38jyfD5oSPWAs"', u'items': [{u'updated': u'2014-10-20T16:55:25.402Z', u'kind': u'plus#activity', u'actor': {u'image': {u'url': u'https://....
```

activities schema:

```
{
  "kind": "plus#activityFeed",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "selfLink": string,
  "nextLink": string,
  "title": string,
  "updated": datetime,
  "id": string,
  "items": [
    activities Resource
  ]
}
```

The objective is represent "items"information.so is a for into other for.

Comment: >> **when trying to iterate over the HTML I have problems** ... what problems? Do you get an error? What error? No errors, just not what you expected? What do you get, what did you expect?

Comment: I don't know how iterate collection into other collection.. The error is Error: <class 'jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError'>. My idea is iterate each item and show the "activities Resource"

Answer (score 1):

"actividades" is truncated but it should be something like

`{% for a in actividades.items %}
   <li>{{a.insert_correct_key_or_property_name_here}}</li>
{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

the functional code is this (similar to Monte Bel comments but using a "[]" to represent collections or properties):
With this case yo can iterate into **items** and show each **activity title.**

```
{% for a in actividades['items'] %}
<li>{{a['title']}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!